# Euclidean distance of a tensor?

Tags: normed-spaces, tensors

The definition of the euclidean norm of matrix is clearly defined:

$$|A|= \sqrt{\sum_{ij} a_{ij}^2}$$

But does it work, if I have a tensor (x,y,$depth>1$) which has a depth $>1$ ($depth == 1$ would be a matrix).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double-dot product is the square of the 2-norm for any second-order tensor $\boldsymbol{S}$. Using Einstein's summation convention, its value may be written
\begin{aligned}
{\|\boldsymbol{S}\|_2}^2 &= \boldsymbol{S} : \boldsymbol{S} \\
&= S_{ij} S_{ij} \\
&= \sum_{ij} {S_{ij}}^2 \, ,
\end{aligned}
where $S_{ij}$ are components of $\boldsymbol{S}$. One may proceed similarly for third-order tensors $\boldsymbol{T}$ by setting
\begin{aligned}
{\|\boldsymbol{T}\|_2}^2 &= T_{ijk} T_{ijk} \\
&= \sum_{ijk} {T_{ijk}}^2\, .
\end{aligned}

---

Note: zeroth-order tensor $\sim$ scalar, first-order tensor $\sim$ vector, second-order tensor $\sim$ matrix.

Comment: what is a second order tensor?

Comment: you have forgotten the  root $\sqrt$ somewhere, didn't you?

Comment: @Peter No, everything is squared. Writing a square root on both side, one has $\|\boldsymbol{T}\|_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{ijk} {T_{ijk}}^2}$.